# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL.The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource

Tags: java

Help me here guys...I have added servlet jar file and mysql connector jar file but it's showing the error like HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL.The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.I have attempted every possible solution but i am getting the same error.

**Regform.java**

```
package com.servlet.info;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Regform extends HttpServlet {


@Override 
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String fNM = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lNM = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String eID = request.getParameter("emailID");
    String uNM = request.getParameter("userName");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");

    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver mySqlDriverClassRef = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
         DriverManager.registerDriver(mySqlDriverClassRef);
//creating connection with the database 
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_form?&useSSL=false", "j2ee" ,"j2ee");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("insert into student values(?,?,?,?,?);");

    ps.setString(1, fNM);
    ps.setString(2, lNM);
    ps.setString(3, eID);
    ps.setString(4, uNM);
    ps.setString(5, pass);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

      if(i>0)
      {
        out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
      }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Register form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/register" method="POST" >
     firstName:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br/>
     lastName:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br/>
     emailID :<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
     userName:<input type="text" name="userName" /><br/>
     Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app  version="3.0" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Regform</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.info.Regform</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Regform</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below to your Java and see if it works

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response) throws       
IOException,
                                                   ServletException {
 doPost(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Did the above suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you always write the codes you defined in the doPost and doGet methods in the doProcess method.